# Construct Equation

Tags: calculus

Construct an equation of a rational function whose graphs has no roots, no holes, vertical asymptotes at x =±2, and a horizontal asymptote at y = 3.

I get everything except how to add the Horizontal asymptote at y=3.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, lmk if im right. 
EDIT: $1/(x^2-4)^2 +3$ This one has no roots

Comment: Your function has two roots, so it doesn't work

Comment: This function has zeroes at $\pm\sqrt{\frac{11}{3}}$.

Comment: oof, can you help me solve it>

Comment: The square on the denominator makes the roots go away, it doesn't affect the asymptotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that works.

I began with $\displaystyle \frac{3x^2}{(x-2)(x+2)}$.

It satisfied the two vertical asymptotes and horizontal, but it still had one root, at $x=0$.

I modified this with $\displaystyle \frac{3x^2+1}{(x-2)(x+2)}$. It no longer had a root at $x=0$, and$f(0)$ was negative, which ensures that there are no roots.